# Prophet and his Prophecy Doubts?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, hadith-interpretation, seerah

A seen in the following Hadith:

> The apostle of Allah took the shoulder, a piece of which he put into his mouth. Bishr [ibn al-Bara] took another bone and put it into his mouth. When the apostle of Allah ate one morsel of it, Bishr ate his, and other people also ate from it. Then the apostle of Allah said, “Hold back your hands! because this shoulder informed me that it is poisoned.” Thereupon Bishr said, “By Him who has made you great! I realised it from the bite I took. The only reason I didn’t spit it out was that I didn’t like to spoil your appetite. When you had eaten what was in your mouth, I did not like to save my life after yours, and **I also thought you would not have eaten it if there was something wrong.**”
>
> Muhammad’s companions dragged Zeynab back into his presence demanding an explanation. She replied: “I was determined to kill you because of what you did to my people. You killed my father, my uncle and my husband. **I thought that if you were a [real] prophet, the poison would not harm you**; but if you were only a[n ordinary] king, I would relieve everyone of you.”

So what does this mean? The woman was right?  The prophet didn't know if the lamb was poison?
I know this is bad source but you might wanna take a look at the article that gave me my doubts: http://www.answering-islam.org/Silas/mo-death.htm

Comment: What doubts are you referring to? The Prophet PBUH did not know until the food told him that it was poisoned. Whatever the woman assumed is on her. Her idea of a Prophet being invincible is irrelevant to the Prophet PBUH.

Comment: Wouldn't it make the prophet a false prophet. As that was the women intention. Check out this link, http://www.answering-islam.org/Silas/mo-death.htm

Comment: It’s irrelevant. What if the woman’s idea was “When I see him, the sun explodes” yet when she sees him, it doesn’t explode. Does that mean the Prophet is fake? Of course not.

Comment: Brother, I really don't want sound like a kafir but something still doesn't satisfy me. The woman gave him, our prophet a lamb which had poison.  The prophet later died from it.  The companions died form eating the poison, if he was truly a prophet he would have been able to stop them by receiving a message.  However in this context, it seems he ate it before he became aware of it. That kind of put doubt in my mind

Comment: The Muslims with the Prophet PBUH also lost the battle of Uhud. Does that mean the Prophet is fake because he didn’t anticipate a battle loss? Whether you have personal doubts or not, the argument you put forth fails.

Comment: Uhh...that actually cleared things up. Thanks brother.

Comment: I'm still willing to see what other people can come up with.

Comment: It would be nice if you presented a source (Book, page/reference), as as is the so called hadith doesn't appear in the link it might be a mix of different narrations, but there are some key expressions which I couldn't even find in there.

Comment: Nahmet, I think what Shadi tries to say is that you can't base your belief of the prophet being a prophet based on the woman's conclusion. Her conclusion might not be correct. For instance in the Quran it mentions people saying: *"how could he be a prophet when he walks and eats like us?"* The solution mentioned in the Qur'an is that he is just a man that gets revelation from God. So the same goes here,  the woman mistakes that in order to be a prophet you will not get effected by poison , which is a false assumption...

Comment: I see what you're saying and it make sense.  But in the Quran, Surah 69:43-69:46 it said "It is] a revelation from the Lord of the worlds.
And if Muhammad had made up about Us some [false] sayings,
We would have seized him by the right hand;
Then We would have cut from him the aorta."

Comment: Then in the Hadith:The Prophet (ﷺ) in his ailment in which he died, used to say, "O `Aisha! I still feel the pain caused by the food I ate at Khaibar, and at this time, I feel as if my aorta is being cut from that poison." May you please explain this to me?

Comment: When the Jew attempted to kill him with poison, Allah protected him from that, and the mutton told him that it was poisoned. The Sahabi who was with him and ate some of it – namely Bishr ibn al-Bara’ ibn Ma‘roor – died but the Prophet (pbuh) did not die because his job was not yet complete as the revelation didnt stop.What he (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said does not mean that the poison was the cause of his death; rather the report indicates that he was feeling it and that that might coincide with the end of his life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Her intention was to kill the Prophet, not just to make him ill. The "harm" she meant there was clearly death because she went on to say, "if you were only a[n ordinary] king, I would **relieve everyone of you**". Did her little scheme relieve everyone of him (ie, his presence and authority)? No. Rather, he continued to be among the people and their leader for another few years. So what she actually did was prove that he was a true Prophet, because A) everyone was not 'relieved of him' and B) any normal person would've died right there from the effects of the poison. He didn't. Allah (ﷻ) still had things for him to accomplish in the world, thus He saved him.

Furthermore, he was still informed miraculously. If you are confused on the "timing" then you need to understand that these things are granted to them by God per His Wisdom. Meaning, there was some reason God allowed him to touch the morsel of food before informing him. But still, the overall point is that he was informed. A normal person wouldn't know until it is too late.