# What is the relationship between theses verse found in the Quran and in the Hadith

Tags: quran, hadith, practical-islam, prophet-muhammad, quran-recitation

Salam, In the Quran,Surah 69:43-69:46 it had said the following

> "It is] a revelation from the Lord of the worlds. And if Muhammad had made up about Us some **[false] sayings**, We would have seized him by the right hand; Then We would have **cut from him the aorta"**

What is fascinating is in the Hadith, I'll say before our Prophet PBUH death, said

> " "O `Aisha! I still feel the pain caused by the food I ate at Khaibar, and at this time, I feel as if my **aorta is being cut** from that poison."

I want know if there was some of connection 
between these verses? Perhaps a inaccurate  verse from the hadith? There was actually a similar post about this found here: [Prophet and his Prophecy Doubts?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/44845/prophet-and-his-prophecy-doubts). But I feel that my question would be more specific. May Allah forgive me for any mistakes I might have made.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having one's aorta cut is an Arabic idiom for dying.

In other words, 69:46 is saying that if Muhammad were to make up revelation, Allah would kill him and nothing could stop that. The hadith is merely saying that Muhammad felt like he was dying from poison.

Claiming a connection here simply because two sources used similar wording to communicate the same idea is a stretch.